# Explicit formula for inverse function for n-th partial sum of harmonic series

Tags: recurrence-relations, harmonic-numbers

Originally, I was trying to work out an explicit formula for a function with the property that $f(x + \frac{1}{f(x)}) = f(x) + k$ for some $k$.

This is inspired by a thing I did with a metronome once, where on each beat I turned the frequency dial up by one tick, if that helps you visualize it.

I have computed some points on this curve for $f(0) = 1$ and $k = 1$:

```
x     | f(x)
------+------
0     | 1
1     | 2
1.5   | 3
1.833 | 4
2.083 | 5
2.283 | 6
2.45  | 7
```

[image: graph]

After computing these points, I realized that this is an inverse function for the n-th partial sum of the harmonic series, or more precisely, $\forall f(x) \in \Bbb Z:\sum_{n=1}^{f(x)} \frac{1}{n} = x$.

**What is an explicit formulation for $f(x)$ over the reals, if such exists?** (Or if not, why.)

Comment: are you thinking of convex interpolation?

Comment: @DavidHolden I was hoping for a function that actually takes on these values because of some underlying mathematical relationship with their source. Not sure exactly what you mean by "convex interpolation" but a quick google turns up things like "interpolation by convex quadratic splines", which is not the sort of thing I am after.

Comment: i was just meaning that as presented, the correspondence is only set up on a discrete set of values. if you haven't chanced upon it you may find it useful that: $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k = \psi(n+1)+\gamma$ where $\psi$ is the logarithmic derivative of the gamma function, and $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant

Comment: So then that would make the solution $f(x) = \psi^{-1}(x - \gamma) - 1$, I think. Is that right?

Comment: Actually no, it'd be $f(x) = \psi^{-1}(x - \gamma)$.

Comment: this is a fairly accessible short treatment of $\psi$ http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116A/psifun_11.pdf i'm just beginning to look at the simplest facts about the "special functions" myself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16415/discussion-between-ajmansfield-and-david-holden).